# How do I get my code to save consistently?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master workbook that allows users to select specific regions and then run a macro to save the workbook with a new name. But before executing the code, my code is written to delete their selections and save the master, then paste their selections into the master and resave with a different workbook name.
At the end of the code, the original master is reopened and should come up as a blank master . . . **but sometimes it saves blank data correctly and other times it saves the master with the user's selection.**

The master workbook is huge and takes several seconds to refresh the data whenever a selection is made or data is cleared. Could this be causing the problem? Here's some of my code. I've added calls to refresh macros in case the user has their settings to manually calculate.

```
Option Explicit


Sub SavetoNewWorkbook()
    With Application
        .StatusBar = "Processing...."
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
'   copying company and division
    Dim Customer As String
    Customer = Budget.Range("A2")

'   clearing contents and saving master as blank
    Range("A2:A3").ClearContents
    Call Refresh
'    MsgBox Customer
    
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    
'   Pasting selected values back in to A2
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = Customer
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Call Refresh
      
'   Saving new workbook with standard file name
    Dim Master As String
    Dim Path1 As String
    Dim PathMaster As String
    Dim MasterNew As String
    Master = ThisWorkbook.Name
    Path1 = ThisWorkbook.Path
    PathMaster = Path1 & "\" & Master
    MasterNew = Budget.Range("A2") & "_Div Code-" & Left(Budget.Range("C2"), 2) & "-" & Right(Budget.Range("C2"), 3) & "_Budget_" & VBA.Format(VBA.Date, "MM-DD-YYYY")
    MsgBox MasterNew
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & MasterNew
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & MasterNew
```

Comment: `Range("A2:A3").ClearContents` - best to specify the workbook/worksheet that the `Range` is in/on. Otherwise you're implicitly working off the `ActiveSheet`, which may or may not be the one you want.

Comment: Thanks Ben, the macro is executed using a button within the worksheet, which is why I didn't specify the worksheet. But, I will add the worksheet name to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You called :

```
Range("A2:A3").ClearContents
```

When using `Range`, always refer to the sheet it should take the range from. If your code uses different workbooks, refer to the workbook as well.

Use instead :

```
Dim ws as Workbook
'Define ws with the workbook you want
ws.Sheets("whateveryoursheetnameis").Range("A2:A3").ClearContents
```

This is because excel doesn't know in what sheet it should use ClearContent

Comment: I added this code and it still doesn't clear the data when saving the master. If I step through the code and give the workbook time to update all the data, then I get the result I want. It's almost as if the code is running faster than the data can update and not waiting until the refresh function is complete before saving.

Comment: This is weird, VBA is a one threaded language, it shouldn't reach `ThisWorkbook.Save` until it finishes the `ClearContents`

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the problem. The excel file was in autosave mode. When I turned autosave off, it worked as it should.